# Can't transform Blob coming from a JSON into file

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, sequelize.js, blob

I have a base64 encoded image saved on mySQL. When i use my API to get the image, it returns a Blob:

[Blob on Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Lwj.png)

But when i try to get the Blob, i receive errors:

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

That error happens on line base64.decode(pictureBlob), so the Blob is a list. But how could i properly get the Blob?

The code that i'm using to get the Blob:

```
  Future<Profile> getProfile(ModelUser user) async {
_headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer ${user.token}";

final response = await get(
    Uri.http(_options.baseUrl, '/persons/${user.id}'),
    headers: _headers);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("ui");
  Map<String, dynamic> profileMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
  var pictureBlob = profileMap['picture'];

  print(pictureBlob);
  print(base64.decode(pictureBlob));

  return Profile.fromJson(profileMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your json. by `var pictureBlob = profileMap['picture'];` this line you will get a map

```
{
  "type" : "Buffer",
  "data" : [47, 57, ......]
}
```

so to get the blob file you need to use

```
//getting the blob from json
var pictureBlob = profileMap['picture']['data'];
//convert it to Uint8List
var image = base64.decode(pictureBlob);
```

then use the image as  `Image.memory(image);`

Comment: Yes, but how could i use it? Actually i'm converting it to a Uint8List, but his value is in base64 so i need to read it and decode before load the image. Buuut, how could i read this blob  back to my base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to make it work on my code. The answer of Tipu Saltan was great but not enough: my node was retrieving the image as Bytes.

Okay, i was senting the picture encoded in base 64. Nothing wrong with that.
But to transform my received bytes into the image, i needed this code:

```
    List<int> pictureData = profileMap['picture']['data'].cast<int>();
    Uint8List pictureBytes = Uint8List.fromList(pictureData);
    String pictureBase64 = new String.fromCharCodes(pictureBytes);

    profileMap['picture'] = base64Decode(pictureBase64);
```

Thanks for the help!